# Resize image with good quality and less weight

Tags: c#, image

I want to resize an image with good quality, and the most important thing is having less weight for an image so that webpages will load it faster.

I am using the below method for this. Please check it out, if it is proper or let me know if it needs any modifications. If there is a better method than this, then also please tell me.

```
public static void ResizeImage(int newWidth, int newHeight, Stream sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourcePath))
    {
        Image imgPhoto = Image.FromStream(sourcePath);

        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

        if (sourceWidth > newWidth || sourceHeight > newHeight)
        {
            //Consider vertical pics
            if (sourceWidth < sourceHeight)
            {
                int buff = newWidth;

                newWidth = newHeight;
                newHeight = buff;
            }

            int destX = 0, destY = 0;
            float nPercent = 0, nPercentW = 0, nPercentH = 0;

            nPercentW = ((float)newWidth / (float)sourceWidth);
            nPercentH = ((float)newHeight / (float)sourceHeight);
            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            {
                nPercent = nPercentH;
                destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((newWidth -
                      (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                nPercent = nPercentW;
                destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((newHeight -
                      (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
            }
        }

        var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
        thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work? Then it's OK.

Comment: @CodeCaster, yes, it is working fine. Is there any improvement need in my code ???

Comment: In my opinion, it hasn't been tested enough, as I can see some cases where it doesn't perform correctly.

Answer (score 3):

- Variable type choice. Why do you use `Int16` and `float`? Most likely you'll be running on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine, and even the 32-bit machines will be optimized for math operations using `double`. I know you don't need perfect accuracy, but using the smaller types is not likely to save you any space or time. The optimizer will probably convert them to `Int32` and `double` anyway and then just round them off/truncate/extend.
- You should declare variables as late as possible. Ideally right before they're initialized. In particular, there's no point in declaring a variable, setting its initial value to 0, and then on the next line setting its value to what you really wanted.
- What is the purpose of `nPercent`, `destX`, and `destY`? You calculate them then throw them away.
- I don't think you tested this code. You have an `if` block that swaps `newWidth` and `newHeight`, but nothing that ever swaps them back. What's the code intended to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing for an old project, and that is getting a thumbnail out of an image, and this was my code for it

```
   public byte[] CreateImageThumbnail(byte[] image, int width = 50, int height = 50)
    {
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image))
        {
            var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            var thumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

            using (var thumbStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                thumbnail.Save(thumbStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return thumbStream.GetBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think its more flexible than yours, because it takes `bytes` and returns `bytes`

Comment: Instead of reviewing the OP's code, you just said "Here's the codez! Look at what I did!". I'm sure it's perfectly valid and maybe better than OP's, but you've not taken the time to say why it's better or bothered to critique the code in the question.

Comment: What is Image.FromStream here, its not defined anywhere

Comment: Got it, its `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream)`